# Is there a way to localize variables to the current function in `mksh` but not to others?

Tags: variable, mksh

Is there a way for `$val` to be set in `a ()` but not be seen by `b ()`?

```
set -u -e -o pipefail


a () {
  local +x val="myval"
  echo "in a: VAL= $val"
  b
}

b () {
  echo "in b: VAL= $val"
}

a
```

Produces:

```
in a: VAL= myval
in b: VAL= myval  # This should not happen.
```

I was hoping to use `local`/`typeset` options instead of the use of subshells to protect variables from being seen in other functions.

I've checked the [manual](https://www.mirbsd.org/htman/i386/man1/mksh.htm) (Functions section, typeset section) and there doesn't seem to be a way.  However, I could have easily missed something.

Comment: `val= b` is a workaround.

Comment: @cuonglm Do you mean setting the value of `$val` inside `b ()`?

Comment: No, change the last line of function a, `b` to `val= b`.

Comment: @cuonglm Thanks, but I've already considered that.  In the real world, I would have to keep track of which variables for different functions. It's more "cognitive load" and for me that leads to more bugs and complicated code.

Comment: Then just do all the work in a subshell, then call `b` outside the subshell.

Comment: @cuonglm Thanks, but I've also considered that. It's not practical in some situations, like `IFS= ; for ... ; do  b; done `.  I also don't want to write function blocks like `( ....; .... ; .... ; ); b;  ( .... ; ... ; ... ; ); c; ( ... )` unless there is a better way. Also, I may want to use the variable before and after `b ()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of restricting variables with subshells, you can run `b` as a new process.  Then it won't have access to any of the caller's variables, except those you chose to export.

## Move function to a new script

If you only need it for a single function, move that whole function into a separate script.

`b`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env mksh
set -u -e -o pipefail

echo "in b: VAL= $val"
```

Output:

```
in a: VAL= myval
./b[4]: val: parameter not set
```

## Use a wrapper function

If you have lots of functions that need this, then you can move them all into a single file, and include a wrapper function to source-and-execute.

`funcs`:

```
#long options not passed on by -$-
set -o pipefail

#execute function without inheriting environment variables
function ni () {
  WHERE="${_%/*}"
  mksh -$- -c "source $WHERE/funcs ; $*"
}

function a () {
  local +x val="myval"
  echo "in a: VAL= $val"
  ni b
}

function b () {
  echo "in b: VAL= $val"
}
```

This "library" will need to be `source`d from the main script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env mksh

set -e -u -o pipefail

WHERE="${_%/*}"
source $WHERE/funcs

a
```

This has the disadvantage that you lose the location (script and line number) of the error:

```
in a: VAL= myval
mksh: val: parameter not set
```

Answer (score 0):

### No.

**However**, if your call to `b` is a tail call and you “only” need to construct its arguments, there’s a way to do that which I’ve used in my “figure out the classpath then run the JAR” script.

```
function a {
    local val …

    # do something with local variables

    # construct arguments by setting the global variable _ to it
    set -A _ -- b arg1…
    # could even unset -f a here
}
a
"${_[@]}"
```

In [my script](https://github.com/tarent/maven-parent/blob/master/lib/run.sh) I’m using `exec "${_[@]}"` as last line as I call an external command, I’m using the local variables technique to avoid accidentally polluting any exported environment variables.

Perhaps this helps?

Full disclosure: I’m the `mksh` developer.